# Search text parts in db tables

Tags: laravel

I have db tables 'books','book_authors' .
And when user search in website for 'John Doe How to be happy' for example.
I wanna search from db for author with name 'John' or 'Doe' or book with title'How to be happy'.

```
 $books = Book::where('book_title','like', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhereHas('authors', function (Builder $q) use ($search) {
            $q->where('name', 'like','%'.$search.'%')
        })->paginate(12);
```

Here my query . But It looks for author with name 'John Doe How to be happy' or for books with title 'John Doe How to be happy' . And results nothing . Is it possible ?

Comment: Typo? in your Where statement you use `$search_word` in the authors where you use `$search`

Comment: @GertB. No it just typo here . It doesnt matter

Comment: I would suggest installing the Laravel debugbar, so you can see your actual query and debug it.

Comment: I would also suggest to not _type_ code here but _copy/paste_ your original code. You might have a typo in your original code that you skip when typing here

Comment: @JKSDS please check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use  `orWhere`

```
$books = Book::where('book_title','like', '%'.$search_word.'%')
         ->orWhereHas('authors', function ($q) use($search) {
            $q->orWhere('name', 'like','%'.$search.'%');
         })->paginate(12);
```

Comment: Can you explain why orWhere inside the OrWhereHas is needed?

Comment: Why ? It will search for book title 'John Doe How to be happy'  on author name 'John Doe How to be happy'  .  Your query works only i will search  for author or book apart .

Comment: The where on the author name is inside the subquesry, that is a OrWhereHas, so i don't think its needed

Answer (score -1):

You can create permutation of search words then use the permutation with [`whereIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) to get the expected result.

```php
$str = "John Doe How to be happy";
$arr = explode(" ", $str);
$book_title = array();
/*
$book_title would look as below after for loop completes
Array
(
    [0] => happy
    [1] => be happy
    [2] => to be happy
    [3] => How to be happy
    [4] => Doe How to be happy
    [5] => John Doe How to be happy
)
*/
$author = array();
/*
$author would look as below after for loop completes
Array
(
    [0] => John
    [1] => Doe
    [2] => How
    [3] => to
    [4] => be
    [5] => happy
)
*/
for ($i = 0, $l = count($arr) - 1; $i <= $l; $i++) {
    array_push($author, $arr[0]);
    array_unshift($book_title, join(" ", $arr));
    array_shift($arr);
}


$books = Book::whereIn('book_title', book_title)
        ->whereHas('authors', function (Builder $q) use ($author) {
            $q->whereIn('name', $author);
        })
        ->paginate(12);
```

I have used [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) with [`where`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) because we want both the condition to be true

Comment: How I will know which part of search query is author name and which part is book title.

Comment: First of all, explain your answer. second, how is this a solution, the question is to use a single variable. And Authors is not a column, but a relationship

Comment: @GertB. thank you for pointing out I have updated my answer with explanation.

Comment: @JKSDS since we don't know if user has passed author name or book name or both thats why we are creating permutation by which we can search.